# Does MS Word have an equivalent of Range.GetSpellingSuggestions for grammar?

Tags: vba, ms-word, spell-checking, office-2013, word-2013

In Microsoft Word 2013 VBA, you can call `GetSpellingSuggestions` on a `Range` that includes a spelling error to get a collection of (a) what the spelling error is and (b) what the proposed suggestions are.  Is there anything equivalent for grammatical errors?  I called `GetSpellingSuggestions` on a `Range` with only a grammatical error and got back `wdSpellingCorrect` with no suggestions.

[This post from 2004](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/10/19/checking-grammar/#comment-2447) says Word doesn't provide that information to VBA, but I'm wondering if Microsoft has added one since then.  I've looked on MSDN and SO and haven't found an answer.  `CheckGrammar` won't work for me since I'm rolling my own UI for the checker.  Thanks!

Comment: I looked on MSDN and it seems like there is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.grammarchecked(v=office.11).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.checkgrammar(v=office.11).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.grammaticalerrors(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @ta - thanks!  Yes, I saw those.  I am calling `GrammaticalErrors` to get the `Ranges` with the errors, but then can't get the suggestions.  I am replacing the UI, so `CheckGrammar` won't work for me.  `GrammarChecked` is the output of the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like the answer is no :/ .  Posting this to get the question off the Unanswered lists.  If you happen across this and have some information, please post another answer!  Thanks!